# How to encrypt/compress a JSON string and use as a URL query?

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I have a website that I want to create a sharable link for. The link currently includes a large JS object as a JSON string.

e.g `mysite.com?share={"foo":1,"bar":2}`

I don't really want the internal state of the page exposed to all my users, so i tried base64 encoding but the url is over 6000 characters long.

Are there any methods to create a more compressed string? I am not too fussed about my more knowledgeable users being able to decode it themselves if they really want to.

My website is currently served by a Node JS server which I can use if there any Node JS techniques to use, though I would rather just use a simple client side option.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: My first instinct is to say 'don't do that' and instead use some counter or other unique identifier. If you must, you can use a secure hash like SHA-256 and the urlsafe-base64 encode the output, resulting in a 44 character hash representation.

Answer (score 0):

Most safe encrypted text would end up your text be larger than original

If you want to at least save your text length, I would suggest you use caesarCipher

```
const caesarCipher = (str, shift, decrypt = false) => {
  const s = decrypt ? (26 - shift) % 26 : shift;
  const n = s > 0 ? s : 26 + (s % 26);
  return [...str]
    .map((l, i) => {
      const c = str.charCodeAt(i);
      if (c >= 65 && c <= 90)
        return String.fromCharCode(((c - 65 + n) % 26) + 65);
      if (c >= 97 && c <= 122)
        return String.fromCharCode(((c - 97 + n) % 26) + 97);
      return l;
    })
    .join('');
};
```

```
caesarCipher('Hello World!', -3); // 'Ebiil Tloia!'
caesarCipher('Ebiil Tloia!', -3, true); // 'Hello World!'
caesarCipher('Ebiil Tloia!', 3); // 'Hello World!'
```

But if you want it to be more safe, there is good encryption js package **crypto-js**

Comment: A stream cipher will keep the text length the same. However, encrypted text will not compress well. Better to compress before encrypting.